# processing Google Form input with GAS and sending a Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

When processing Google Form input with GAS and sending a Gmail, sometimes the same email is sent multiple times to the same recipient. Can you tell me what the cause might be?

・How can I verify that duplicated emails have different message IDs?
・How can I keep track and confirm that form submissions are only done once in a Google spreadsheet?
I expect that only one email is sent to the form submitter per form submission.

Comment: Have the email sent include a timestamp and form submission id for testing purposes.

Comment: In the past there have been several times when onSubmitForm  was sending spurious triggers.  You could use an alreadySent flag and check that it's false prior to sending.  You could store it in Properties Service or CacheService